# Shell function command with quotes

Tags: bash, shell, command-line-interface, zsh

I am trying to make a `git` shortcut to commit with a message. Since aliases do not support parameters I came up with this function:

```
function gcm() { git commit -m "$@" }
```

My expectation is to commit with a message without even typing quotes like this:

```
gcm create cli module
```

However I get an error, probably due to the string interpolation when expanding the all-params symbol.

```
error: pathspec 'cli' did not match any file(s) known to git.
error: pathspec 'module' did not match any file(s) known to git.
```

How can I fix the function so I can have an alias that saves me from typing quotes?

**UPDATE:**

I love this shortcut so much that I must make a copy paste friendly version of the solution for everyone

```
alias gcm='function() { git commit -a -m "$*" }'
```

Comment: In most shells, you will need a semicolon (or a newline) before the closing curly bracket in the function definition.  This is a POSIX weirdness, I believe.

Comment: It's a much better idea to quote the commit message as a single argument, rather than treat it as a string of separate arguments to be joined with whitespace. You don't want your commit message to depend on the current value of the `IFS` shell parameter.

Comment: The semicolon is required because `}` is not a reserved word when closing a compound command. This allows something like `{ echo foo; echo bar }; }` to work, with the second command printing `bar }`. See the RESERVED WORDS section of the `bash` man page.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You want `"$*"` not `"$@"` because you want the arguments expanded as a single word not multiple words.

This is one of the few times the `"$*"` expansion is actually desirable. It generally isn't.

Comment: You should definitely take chepner's comments into consideration. Personally I wouldn't be concerned about the `IFS` problem (but I *never* mess with `IFS` except in *very* specific (and tightly scoped) circumstances. But the comments about spaces collapsing/etc. and special characters still needing to be quoted are both good ones. Additionally, personally, I think limiting commit messages to single lines is generally a poor practice (though for some commits it is clearly sufficient).

Comment: I work with short lived feature branches with a high number of impulsive micro commits briefly commented with few words. Those are the target of my alias.  The merge of the feature branch is a whole different story and I take my time to write a good message (even squash some micro commits). I envy people who can write good multi line messages on every commit, but for me a workflow with higher number of commits has priority.

Answer (score 2):

Make your commit message a single argument, not a sequence of separate arguments.

```
gcm () { git commit -m "$1"; }
```

and invoke it like this:

```
gcm "My commit message"
```

This way, you get the exact text you type in your commit message, without the following happening:

- Multiple consecutive spaces collapsed to one space
- Other whitespace such as tabs and newlines converted to spaces
- Characters like `*` would need to be quoted anyway to prevent special interpretation by the shell.
- If the value of `IFS` is changed for some reason, it will affect the content of your commit message:

  ```
  $ gcm () { echo "$*"; }
  $ gcm my    commit message
  my commit message
  $ IFS=:
  $ gym my    commit message
  my:commit:message
  ```